# null bundle in fragment , what is the right way to get a bundle in fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bundle

i have an activity with multiple buttons , when clicking a button a new activity with two fragments get opened .

i am trying to display a Recyclerview in one of those fragments depending on the button pressed .
the problem is the bundle is null so the recyclerview doesnt show .

the bundle is not null in `onAttach`,but its null in `settextview` method

**fragment**

public class MyFragment extends Fragment  {

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private static TextView input ;
private static RecyclerView rv ;
private Handler mhandler = new Handler();
public  Bundle bundle;
public String data;

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
      input  =view.findViewById(R.id.input);
       rv =view.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    return view;
}
public void setTextView(String text){

    input.setText(text);

    String[] numberList = input.getText().toString();
    final Integer[] numbers = new Integer[numberList.length];

    ArrayList<String> List ;
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter() ;
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    System.out.println("setextview "+bundle);

    if(bundle != null){
        if (sort1.equals("se")) {
            ClassA m1 = new ClassA();
            List = m1.etap(numbers);
            adapter.setList(mystepsList);

        }else if (sort1.equals("in")) {
            ClassB = new ClassB();
            List = m1.etap(numbers);
            adapter.setList(mystepsList);
        } }
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
    bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    sort1 =b.getString("value");
    System.out.println("onAttach "+bundle);
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can it if get extra is null or null, if not null again you can cross check with the key you want to get via containsKey() to check if bundle have data respective to this key or not.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("value") {
            boolean value = bundle.getStringExtra("value");
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Bundle is Null or don't have key");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to pass data from activity to fragment

**In Activity**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

**In Fragment**

> Bundle bundle= getArguments();

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Bundle bundle= getArguments();
      if(bundle!=null){
         String strtext = bundle.getString("edttext"); 
       }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```